# GEKKO Result explanation

Tags: python, gekko

would you mind sparing some time explaining why the `Obj` is zero here in some iterations?

[image]

`tcstd` and `tdstd` is min-max standardize of `tc` and `td`. I want to minimize `tcstd*tdstd` so the value of objective function should be `0-1`. however during the process, the obj appears to be 0 but not define as optimal solution ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The lines listed as zero objective are either non-integer solutions or non-feasible solutions. The lines with:

```
--Integer solution:
```

identify when the solver finds a candidate integer solution. The other lines are either successful (non-integer) with `I:0`

```
Iter :28 I: 0 Tm: 0.00 NLPi: 3 Dpth: 7 Lvs: 1 Obj: 0.00E00 Gap: 5.22E-0.2
```

or unsuccessful (`I:<=-1`) and therefore not candidate solutions with

```
Iter:29 I:-9 Tm :0.06 NLPi: 251 Dpth: 3 Lvs: 0 Obj: 7.36E-04 Gap: 5.15E-02
```

The final message is:

```
No additional trial points, returning the best integer solution 
Successful solution
```

This says that there are no additional candidate solutions to try in the [branch and bound approach](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/DiscreteOptimization). The best integer solution is returned.

In the future, please include a text version of the error instead of an image. It makes it easier for those with similar questions to find the question.